# Can i navigate from myonepage.xaml to secondpage.xaml without using the "new Uri" object in windows phone 8

Tags: object, windows-phone-8, navigation, uri, navigationservice

i am facing a problem; during navigating the two pages my application is crashing.

is it possible following scenario in windows phone 8 ?

```
//In Myonepage.xaml on button click
MySecondpage mypageobject = new MySecondpage();

NavigationService.Source(mypageobject); 
// i know above syntax is not possible but i want something like this. actually i don't want to create new Uri object for navigate to the secondpage.xaml.
```

If anyone know this scenario to execute than please let me know.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigat(new Uri(@"/SecondPage.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));   This is how its done

Comment: Anthony Russell,

you are right it is the proper way to do it, but do you know 'new Uri' is creating the new object of the page ? and this is generating problem for me, i don't want to call my second page by creating new Uri object, its occupy the memory again and again. i am facing problem because i am doing some memory operations on secondpage so as i redirect with 'new Uri' it will create new object of the page and i face problem when navigate from onepage.xaml to secondpage.xaml.

Comment: When your app loads, it loads the mainpage, but not the other pages. So, when you call your second page, I guess you need to load it, and therefore, call the object that generates it. I might be wrong, but I think it's something like that

Comment: @AshishJain Any residual changes on a page should cache to the isolated storage. Then on NavigatedFrom you dispose of the page. Usually this is handled for you so you must be doing some really weird operations. I would evaluate your architecture if you are having questions like this. You're likely doing something wrong.